# 1 stick of 4x4 gb wont be recognized as 16gb BUT 4gb

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, motherboard, bios

I have one RAM stick modell `CML16GX3M4A1600C9` Corsair 1600mhz  (4x4gb)16GB . First i used two RAMS sticks modell `BLS4G3D1609DS1S00.16FED2` 4GB each and my computer works good with 8 gb installed , and when i want to upgrade for my new RAM above i installed it in the first place A1 But it recognized only 4gb , changed to all places but still 4gb . IN bios shows 4GB and in z-cpu shows 4gb as well .

I tried removed the battery CMOS to reset but didnt help .

Tryed chagning XMP to profile 1 nothing helps.

Tryed looking for ram remap but its ON , tryed ON and OFF both not working.

Tryed memtest all is ok .

tryed place the Ram stick in every ram stock and all shows 4 gb

I dont know if its due to previous RAM or its something wrong in my pc or bios.

INFO:

motherboard : B85M-G
BIOS VERSION : 2501

CPU:   I7 4790 CPU 3.60ghz  speed 3611 Mhz

WINDOWS OS: windows 7 ultimate x64

Any help please i want have 16gb . i have tryed many things and looked various websites out there and nothing helped .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ram stick (CML16GX3M4A1600C9) you wrote seems to be a set of 4 ram sticks with 4GB each (4x4GB). Are you sure the ram you are using is a single 16GB ram ?
From the statement it seems to me like you are using only one out of the four 4GB ram set. In this case it is natural that the BIOS only detects 4GB.

Comment: yes its only one stick, i hold it in my hand, from the module name you know what is it if its 4x4 or 16, AND even if its 4x4 =16 why it doesnt recognized as 16? if the case why they sell this as 16gb if it will be just 4 recognized .

Comment: The product [CML16GX3M4A1600C9] is a four stick ram kit with 4GB in each stick. It only will show 16GB on your BIOS when you install all 4 sticks. With only 1 stick installed, it is completely normal to show 4GB, since one stick only has 4GB of ram soldered.
If you only have one stick in your hand, I suggest you to contact your seller for details. This product [CML16GX3M4A1600C9] SHOULD come with 4 sticks, not one.

Comment: yes i have 4 of them , i have put all of them in my sockets hoping it will give 64gb but it doesnt so i wanted in the end use just one stick of 16gb but as you know my problem it gives 4gb , how should i do then ? or how i will install the rest to give 16 ?

Comment: if i put all thos sticks to give 64 , it gives just 16gb .

Comment: The product is a 16GB kit, so ”if i put all thos sticks to give 64 , it gives just 16gb" this state is correct, it will give 16GB since one stick has 4GB, not 16GB. Your recognition is incorrect, the total will be 16GB (4GB per stick), not 64GB.

Comment: it should have max 8gb per slot to give 32 in all slots , why then it recognize just 4gb per slot ?

Answer (score 0):

The ASUS B85M-G (R2.0) has four RAM slots while the RAM in these four slots may not exceed 32GB, which implies there is a 8GB limit per slot.

Your choice of trying to use 1 16GB stick is not good, because you will not benefit from dual channel (assuming it would work, which it does not).
Since you already had 2x4GB, you should of added another pair of 2x4 or 2x8GB modules.

Check the complete RAM module support [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/B85-PLUS/B85_Series_Memory_QVL_Report_160427.pdf).

If yours is listed, update the BIOS and then it should work.
If it is not listed, it will most likely not work even with BIOS update.

Comment: ok so slot is limited by 8gb , where can i see that limit per slot ? so i will be sure for that and sell my new rams.

Comment: Check the [Manual for ASUS B85M-G](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/B85M-G/E9884_B85M-G_Manual_v4_print_vendor_only.pdf?_ga=1.179668900.1026521266.1461660532). Look under headline **1.4**. "You may install 1GB, 2GB, 4GB, and 8GB unbuffered non-ECC DDR3 DIMMs into the DIMM 
sockets"

Comment: and if 8 is max ram per slot , why then it gives 4gb why not 8gb as mine is 16gb ?

Comment: and also it saids under 1.4.2 `The maximum 32GB memory capacity can be supported with 8GB or **above** DIMMs` so maybe i can use 2 16 rams , or it should recognize my ram as 8gb not 4 or what  you said @overmind ?

Comment: Check the updated list of supported modules in my answer.

Comment: i checked and its not listed there.